# why I can't iterate through anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

ControllerAction:

```
{

    AddLeadSourcesModel model = new AddLeadSourcesModel();
    List<LeadSourceModel> models = LeadSourceModel.Get()
                                                  .Where(c => c.Active == true)
                                                  .ToList();
    var A = LeadSourceModel.GetSubLeadSources(leadSourceID);
    model.LeadSources = new SelectList(
        LeadSourceModel.Get().Where(c => c.Active == true), 
        "LeadSourceID", 
        "Name", 
        models.Where(c => c.LeadSourceID == leadSourceID).FirstOrDefault().LeadSourceID
    );

    model.SubLeadSources = new SelectList(A, "LeadSourceID", "Name");

    var flattenedData = model.SubLeadSources.SelectMany(subLead => model.LeadSources, (n, a) => new { n,a });

    return PartialView("_AddLeadSources", flattenedData.ToList());

}
```

View:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lead Source</td>
        <td>Sub Lead Source</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.a</td>
        <td>@item.n</td>
        <td><a href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My problem is when I get to the partial it says it expects a different type but I've not told it a type. And I technically don't know the type coz it's annoymous

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You can't use a strongly-typed view with an anonymous type.

Comment: What does your `@model` line in your view even look like with an anonymous type? Did you try `@model var` or something?

Comment: it doesn't have one. I have given everything in the view. I thought the @model makes it strongly typed?

Comment: Yeah, you can't pass anonymous types outside of the method they're created in.

Comment: amy was more on the money. It still didn't work despite using a custom type. COPY AND PASTE FAIL

Comment: @itsme86 Sure you can. https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMuRLe

Comment: @mason Sorry, I meant pass *to* a method. Your example returns an anonymous type, but OP was trying to pass anonymous type as an argument.

Comment: @itsme86 Wrong again. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jquTdY

Comment: @mason Alright, I concede defeat on this one. I was totally wrong.

Comment: @mason - What do you expect to be able to do with that type?  You cannot access it properties outside the method in which it was created, so what use is it?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I didn't say it was useful. I just said it could be done. Anyways, stating you can't access the properties outside the method it was created in is, is incorrect. You could use reflection to obtain the properties and their values. One scenario I can think of off the top of my head is a tool like RazorEngine or [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/). You could pass an anonymous type to a templating engine. May be more uses out there.

Comment: You could use a `ValueTuple` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you've defined class `PartialView` with a constructor that takes two parameters.

Alas you forgot to give us the signature of this constructor, but I think that the first one is a string, the second one is list / sequence / collection of some defined type. I expect something like:

```
class PartialView
{
     public PartialView(string txt, List<MyType> items) {...}
}
```

If you want to use this constructor you'll have to provide a `List<MyType>`. To do this, use `Select` before you create FlattenedData:

```
List<MyType> flattenedData = model.SubLeadSources
    .SelectMany(subLead => model.LeadSources, (n, a) => new { n,a })
    .Select(item => new MyType()
    {
        // fill the MyType properties, something like:
        N= item.n
        A = item.a,
    };
```

Now you can use the constructor.

```
PartialView partialView = new PartialView("_AddLeadSources", flattenedData);
```

### Extension Function

If you'll convert quite often some anonymous type to a sequence of MyType and a PartialView, consider creating an extension function that will take as input a sequence of any (anonymous) type, a string, and two lambda expressions that will tell you which values of the anonymous types are the A and N.

See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

We already know that MyType has properties like A and an N, where you'd like to put your anonymous a and n in. Let's assume they have non-generic type Atype and Ntype, for instance int, or DateTime, or MyElaborateClass, like this:

```
class MyType
{
     public Atype A {get; set;}
     public Btype B {get; set;}
}
```

Extension class for PartialView:

```
static class PartialViewExtension
{
    // Creates one PartialView object from a sequence of MyType objects and a text
    public static PartialView ToPartialView(this IEnumerable<MyType> source, string text)
    {
         return  new PartialView(text, source.ToList());
    }

    // uses the source + predicates to create a sequence of MyType objects
    public static IEnumerable<MyType> ToMyType<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, Atype> aSelector,
        Func<TSource, Ntype> nSelector)
    {
         return source.Select(sourceItem => new MyType()
         {
              A = aSelector(sourceItem),
              B = bSelector(sourceItem),
         });
    }
}
```

Usage would be like:

```
var flattenedData = model.SubLeadSources
    .SelectMany(subLead => model.LeadSources, (n, a) => new { n,a });

PartialView partialView = flattenedData
      .ToMyType(flattenedInput => flattenedInput.n,
                flattendInput => flattenedInput.a)
      .ToPartialView("_AddLeadSources");
```

Now that we are already creating extension functions, lets combine these two into one, that will call the other two:

```
public static PartialView ToPartialView<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    string text,
    Func<TSource, Atype> aSelector,
    Func<TSource, Ntype> nSelector)
{
    return source.ToMyType(aSelector, bSelector).ToPartialView(text);
}
```

Usage:

```
var flattenedData = model.SubLeadSources
    .SelectMany(subLead => model.LeadSources, (n, a) => new { n,a });

PartialView = flattenedData.ToPartialView("_AddLeadSources",
    flattenedInput => flattenedInput.a,
    flattenedInput => flattenedInput.n);
```